Regex which matches two lines text not containing a space or a specific string
I'm searching for a regex that matches a two lines string with the following characteristic:
[any number of any character]"[any number of any character][not a space and not a backslash followed by the char n]"
[any number of spaces]"[not a space][any number of any character]"

i.e. it should match:
1)
abc def "ghi jkl"
     "mno pqr"

but not
2)
abc def "ghi jkl "
     "mno pqr"

nor
3)
abc def "ghi jkl"
     " mno pqr"

nor
4)
abc def "ghi jkl\n"
     "mno pqr"

I'm using the regex: ".*[^\s]"\s+"[^\s].*"
It works well with 1), 2) and 3) but obviously not with 4).

Try: "\S.*\S"\s+"\S.*\S"? Do you need full match? Do you want to extract those in the quotes? ^(?m)[^"\r\n]+"\S.*\S"\s+"\S.*\S"\s*$. Is this valid? abc def "s"      "s"

Your recent edit changed [not a space and not the string '\n'] to [not a space and not a backslash followed by the char n]. Both are confusing, but especially the current one, because a backslash followed by the character 'n' means two characters, not an escaped 'n'; that is, a newline character (\n). I suggest [a character other than a space or newline character].

<> means a backslash followed by the char n literally i.e. 2 characters, not a newline.

You could have avoided all the confusion over your question had you written the strings properly, with quote marks. For example, instead of abc def "ghi jkl\n" you should have written "abc def \"ghi jkl\\n\"". What you have done is akin to writing an array as 1, 2, 3 rather than [1, 2, 3]. I'm downvoting the question for the vagueness of your question.

I've just listed the text that should and shouldn't be matched. In the text there is the string \n" literally, not \n".

Using negative lookbehind
.*".*(?<! |\\n)"\n\s*"(?! )..*"


You are right.
if you change \s+ to \s* it will work for this as well.
In the question it says any number of space in the second line, but I used \s+ which matches the string only if at least one space exists in the second line. So my mistake.
The new answer would be Demo
.*".*((?<! |\\n))"\n\s*"(?! )..*"

I've updated my original answer

Updated my answer, based on your Negative lookbehind sugestion!

In appears you can avoid the negative lookahead by writing  .*".*((?<! |\\n))"\n\s*"[^ \n].*".

Is there a reason for using a capture group rather than a non-capture group? If the regex engine supports non-capture groups (most do) it's best to only use capture groups when you back-reference its contents or intend to its contents later in your code. If your code contains a capture group when a non-capture group would do readers of your code may assume the contents of the group will be used later in your code and waste time looking for that. Not a biggie, of course.

Nice catches @CarySwoveland! There is a big performance benefit by just removing the capture group (30 milliseconds less in 1000 calls). Removing the negative lookahead also has a performance benefit, but very small (0.2 milliseconds in 1000 calls)

You may wish to edit your answer, after which I will remove my comments as they will no longer be relevant, then you might clean things up by removing your comments.

@CarySwoveland, these conversations in the comments are great for future readers. Quite a bit of info for performance. I'd love to keep it

Meanwhile, I've updated my original answer to remove the group captures

If you want to extract those two substrings, you can use:
^(?m)[^"\r\n]+"(\S.*\S)"\s+"(\S.*\S)"\s*$

and if not:
^(?m)[^"\r\n]+"\S.*\S"\s+"\S.*\S"\s*$


Unfortunately the proposed regex incorrectly matches also if the text enclosed in double  quotation marks in the first line ends with a backslash followed by an n like abc def "ghi jkl\n" https://regex101.com/r/EArk1N/1

Edited my answer based on Negative Lookbehind of Sina-sarshar-pour answer:
.*[^\s](?<!\b\\n\b)"\s+"[^\s].*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78631164/1856745
Tests :
Sublime Text.
https://regex101.com/r/nb0dQy/1
https://regexr.com/81o2m

Unfortunately the proposed regex incorrectly doesn't match also if the text enclosed in double quotation marks in the first line ends with a backslash like abc def "ghi jkl" regex101.com/r/aJ3iG1/1 and if it ends with an n not preceded by a backslash like abc def "ghi jkln" regex101.com/r/JmTHwR/1

This was not at your first version of your question.
Would the pattern of your text would be like
[any number of any character]"[any number of any character][(not a space) and ((not a backslash) or (not a backslash followed by the char n))]"
[any number of spaces]"[not a space][any number of any character]"

In the first version I wrote <<not a space and not the string '\n'>> intending <>

As I understand the question you wish to determine if strings match the following regular expression.
(?x)     # invoke extended (aka free-spacing) mode
^        # match beginning of the string
[^"\n]*  # match zero or more chars other than line terminators
         # and double-quotes
"        # match a double-quote
[^"\n]*  # match zero or more chars other than line terminators
         # and double-quotes
(?<!     # begin a negative lookbehind
  \      # match a space
  |      # or
  \\n    # match a backslash followed by n
)        # end negative lookbehind
"        # match a double-quote
\n       # match a newline
\ *      # match zero or more spaces
"        # match double-quote
[^ "\n]  # match a character other than a space, double-quote or newline
[^"\n]*  # match zero or more chars other than line terminators 
         # and double-quotes
"        # match a double-quote
\n?      # optionally match a newline
$        # match end of string

I have written this in extended (aka free-spacing) mode1 to make clear the assumptions I have made. If any are incorrect you can make any needed adjustments. You wrote, for example, "any number of any character". I assumed you actually meant, "any number of any characters other than double-quotes and newlines". Similarly, I assumed "not a space or backslash followed by 'n'" means the string preceding the second double-quote cannot end in a space or a backslash followed by 'n'.
This regex matches the following two (two-line) strings.
a c"d1 %"
   "&g i"

"9"
"&"

It does not match the following three strings, the first because a space is not permitted before the second double-quote, the second because a backslash followed by 'n' cannot precede the second double-quote and the third because a space is not permitted after the third double-quote.
d a"fe "
"3h j"
a c"d1 \n"
"&g i"
a"de f%x"
" &12 "
Regex demo
Note that I have selected the PCRE2 regex engine at the above link, but the regular expression I have proposed does not employ any advanced regex features so it should be compatible with most regex engines.
1. When using extended mode all comments and whitespaces are stripped out before the expression is parsed. Whitespace that is to be part of the expression must therefore be protected. Here I must protect space characters. I've done that by escaping them (\ ). Another common technique is to put them in a character class ([ ]).

Unfortunately the proposed regex incorrectly matches also if the text enclosed in double quotation marks in the first line ends with a backslash followed by an n like abc def "ghi jkl\n" https://regex101.com/r/CKSDKv/1

I understand the difference between a newline character and the two-characters sequence comprised of a backslash and the letter 'n', so I wrote <<not a space and not the string '\n'>> and, to be more clear, I edited it <> which I think it means not a space and not a backslash followed by the char n literally i.e. 2 characters (otherwise I would have written <>.
